# What is CRONTAB doing?

Tags: cron, debian

Is this normal?

```
pi@RaspberryGate:~ $ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Jul 28 06:17:04 RaspberryGate cron[370]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jul 28 06:17:04 RaspberryGate cron[370]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jul 28 06:34:14 RaspberryGate CRON[678]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jul 28 06:17:04 RaspberryGate cron[368]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jul 28 06:17:04 RaspberryGate cron[368]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jul 28 06:47:41 RaspberryGate CRON[644]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jul 28 06:17:04 RaspberryGate cron[371]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jul 28 06:17:04 RaspberryGate cron[371]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jul 28 07:16:24 RaspberryGate CRON[728]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jul 28 07:17:01 RaspberryGate CRON[860]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 28 08:17:01 RaspberryGate CRON[2090]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: Based on the Debian tag and the username and hostname, I would assume you're using Rasbian, not Ubuntu. Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats is correct, and i think after reading and asking several people this is definitely normal, ill marked this as answerd. I actually narrowed down that i have an internal 500 error im not sure how to fix or start troubleshooting though

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the entries like

```
Jul 28 06:34:14 RaspberryGate CRON[678]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
```

then yes, they are normal - *for Debian-based systems*

From the `DEBIAN SPECIFIC` section of `man cron`:

> Support for  /etc/cron.hourly,  /etc/cron.daily,  /etc/cron.weekly 
>   and    /etc/cron.monthly  is provided in Debian through the default
>   setting of    the /etc/crontab file (see the system-wide example in
>   crontab(5)).  The    default  system-wide crontab contains four tasks:
>   run every hour, every    day, every week and every month. **Each of
>   these tasks will execute  run-parts providing each one of the
>   directories as an argument**. These tasks    are disabled if anacron is
>   installed (except for the  hourly  task)  to    prevent conflicts
>   between both daemons.